# Terraform script for provisioning azure Virtual machine scale set along with custom data or cloud init

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, newrelic, azure-vm-scale-set, newrelic-platform

I would like to know the terraform script for provisioning azure Virtual machine scale set along with custom data or cloud init.

I tried many ways to run my script against VMSS but its not working.As per my understanding during provisioning of VMSS I should run some shell scripts so that It can install necessary agents (New relic) into all VMSS instances.

Looking for terraform script for VMSS along with custom data or cloudinit configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the below solution finally I could able to accomplish via terraform using custom data.

```
terraform {
required_version = ">=0.12"

required_providers {
azurerm = {
source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
version = "~>2.0"
}
}
}



provider "azurerm" {
features {}
}



resource "azurerm_resource_group" "vmss" {
name = var.resource_group_name
location = var.location
tags = var.tags
}



resource "random_string" "fqdn" {
length = 6
special = false
upper = false
number = false
}



resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vmss" {
name = "vmss-vnet"
address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
location = var.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.vmss.name
tags = var.tags
}



resource "azurerm_subnet" "vmss" {
name = "vmss-subnet"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.vmss.name
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vmss.name
address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}



resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vmss" {
name = "vmss-public-ip"
location = var.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.vmss.name
allocation_method = "Static"
domain_name_label = random_string.fqdn.result
tags = var.tags
}




resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "vmss" {
name = "vmscaleset"
location = var.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.vmss.name
upgrade_policy_mode = "Manual"



sku {
name = "Standard_DS1_v2"
tier = "Standard"
capacity = 2
}



storage_profile_image_reference {
publisher = "Canonical"
offer = "UbuntuServer"
sku = "16.04-LTS"
version = "latest"
}



storage_profile_os_disk {
name = ""
caching = "ReadWrite"
create_option = "FromImage"
managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"

}



os_profile {
computer_name_prefix = "vmlab"
admin_username = var.admin_user
admin_password = var.admin_password
**custom_data = file("test.sh") **// This is the key line to pass any custom data to VMSS so that during VM spin up each time automatically script will be invoked and will be executed.**
}



os_profile_linux_config {
disable_password_authentication = false
}
network_profile {
name = "terraformnetworkprofile"
primary = true



ip_configuration {
name = "IPConfiguration"
subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.vmss.id
#load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bpepool.id]
primary = true
}
}
tags = var.tags
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one a while ago:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "jumpserver" {
  name                = "${local.prefix}-jumpservers-vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.deployment.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.deployment.location
  sku                 = "Standard_B2s"
  instances           = 2

  overprovision          = false
  single_placement_group = false

  admin_username = "adminuser"
  admin_password = azurerm_key_vault_secret.vmsecret.value

  disable_password_authentication = false

  custom_data = base64encode(data.local_file.cloudinit.content)

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"
    sku       = "20_04-lts"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "${local.prefix}-jumpserver-vmss-nic"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "${local.prefix}-jumpserver-vmss-ipconfig"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.jumpservers_vmss.id
    }
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = null
  }
}

# Data template cloud-init bootstrapping file used by the VMSS
data "local_file" "cloudinit" {
  filename = "${path.module}/cloudinit.conf"
}
```

cloudinit.conf

```
#cloud-config

bootcmd:
  - mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/walinuxagent.service.d
  - echo "[Unit]\nAfter=cloud-final.service" > /etc/systemd/system/walinuxagent.service.d/override.conf
  - sed "s/After=multi-user.target//g" /lib/systemd/system/cloud-final.service > /etc/systemd/system/cloud-final.service
  - systemctl daemon-reload

package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

# Add external package sources, e.g. for Microsoft packages and Kubernetes
apt:
    preserve_sources_list: true
    sources_list: |
      deb $MIRROR $RELEASE main restricted
      deb-src $MIRROR $RELEASE main restricted
      deb $PRIMARY $RELEASE universe restricted
      deb $SECURITY $RELEASE-security multiverse
    sources:
        microsoft-azurecli.list:
            source: "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli focal main"
            key: |
                -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
                Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)

                mQENBFYxWIwBCADAKoZhZlJxGNGWzqV+1OG1xiQeoowKhssGAKvd+buXCGISZJwT
                LXZqIcIiLP7pqdcZWtE9bSc7yBY2MalDp9Liu0KekywQ6VVX1T72NPf5Ev6x6DLV
                7aVWsCzUAF+eb7DC9fPuFLEdxmOEYoPjzrQ7cCnSV4JQxAqhU4T6OjbvRazGl3ag
                OeizPXmRljMtUUttHQZnRhtlzkmwIrUivbfFPD+fEoHJ1+uIdfOzZX8/oKHKLe2j
                H632kvsNzJFlROVvGLYAk2WRcLu+RjjggixhwiB+Mu/A8Tf4V6b+YppS44q8EvVr
                M+QvY7LNSOffSO6Slsy9oisGTdfE39nC7pVRABEBAAG0N01pY3Jvc29mdCAoUmVs
                ZWFzZSBzaWduaW5nKSA8Z3Bnc2VjdXJpdHlAbWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbT6JATUEEwEC
                AB8FAlYxWIwCGwMGCwkIBwMCBBUCCAMDFgIBAh4BAheAAAoJEOs+lK2+EinPGpsH
                /32vKy29Hg51H9dfFJMx0/a/F+5vKeCeVqimvyTM04C+XENNuSbYZ3eRPHGHFLqe
                MNGxsfb7C7ZxEeW7J/vSzRgHxm7ZvESisUYRFq2sgkJ+HFERNrqfci45bdhmrUsy
                7SWw9ybxdFOkuQoyKD3tBmiGfONQMlBaOMWdAsic965rvJsd5zYaZZFI1UwTkFXV
                KJt3bp3Ngn1vEYXwijGTa+FXz6GLHueJwF0I7ug34DgUkAFvAs8Hacr2DRYxL5RJ
                XdNgj4Jd2/g6T9InmWT0hASljur+dJnzNiNCkbn9KbX7J/qK1IbR8y560yRmFsU+
                NdCFTW7wY0Fb1fWJ+/KTsC4=
                =J6gs
                -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        microsoft-prod.list:
            source: "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main"
            key: |
                -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
                Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)

                mQENBFYxWIwBCADAKoZhZlJxGNGWzqV+1OG1xiQeoowKhssGAKvd+buXCGISZJwT
                LXZqIcIiLP7pqdcZWtE9bSc7yBY2MalDp9Liu0KekywQ6VVX1T72NPf5Ev6x6DLV
                7aVWsCzUAF+eb7DC9fPuFLEdxmOEYoPjzrQ7cCnSV4JQxAqhU4T6OjbvRazGl3ag
                OeizPXmRljMtUUttHQZnRhtlzkmwIrUivbfFPD+fEoHJ1+uIdfOzZX8/oKHKLe2j
                H632kvsNzJFlROVvGLYAk2WRcLu+RjjggixhwiB+Mu/A8Tf4V6b+YppS44q8EvVr
                M+QvY7LNSOffSO6Slsy9oisGTdfE39nC7pVRABEBAAG0N01pY3Jvc29mdCAoUmVs
                ZWFzZSBzaWduaW5nKSA8Z3Bnc2VjdXJpdHlAbWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbT6JATUEEwEC
                AB8FAlYxWIwCGwMGCwkIBwMCBBUCCAMDFgIBAh4BAheAAAoJEOs+lK2+EinPGpsH
                /32vKy29Hg51H9dfFJMx0/a/F+5vKeCeVqimvyTM04C+XENNuSbYZ3eRPHGHFLqe
                MNGxsfb7C7ZxEeW7J/vSzRgHxm7ZvESisUYRFq2sgkJ+HFERNrqfci45bdhmrUsy
                7SWw9ybxdFOkuQoyKD3tBmiGfONQMlBaOMWdAsic965rvJsd5zYaZZFI1UwTkFXV
                KJt3bp3Ngn1vEYXwijGTa+FXz6GLHueJwF0I7ug34DgUkAFvAs8Hacr2DRYxL5RJ
                XdNgj4Jd2/g6T9InmWT0hASljur+dJnzNiNCkbn9KbX7J/qK1IbR8y560yRmFsU+
                NdCFTW7wY0Fb1fWJ+/KTsC4=
                =J6gs
                -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        kubernetes:
            source: "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"
            keyid: 7F92E05B31093BEF5A3C2D38FEEA9169307EA071

# Install packages via apt. To add packages it might be required to add additional sources above.
packages:
 - unzip
 - git
 - wget
 - curl
 - apt-transport-https
 - software-properties-common
 - powershell
 - azure-cli
 - npm
 - docker.io
 - packages-microsoft-prod
 - dotnet-sdk-6.0
 - kubectl

# Install latest version of azcopy (can not be installed via apt)
runcmd:
# Download AzCopy and extract archive
 - wget https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux
 - tar -xvf downloadazcopy-v10-linux
# Move AzCopy to the destination
 - sudo cp ./azcopy_linux_amd64_*/azcopy /usr/bin/
# Allow execution for all users
 - sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/azcopy

# create the docker group
groups:
  - docker

# Add default auto created user to docker group
system_info:
  default_user:
    groups: [docker]

final_message: "The system is finally up, after $UPTIME seconds"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Could you please let me know what your cloudinit.conf is doing here? So that I will relate this with my script below. I would like to install newrelic infra agent in all my VMSS instances during provisioning so the below script if I want to run then should I keep this in cloudinit.conf?
Script:

echo "license_key: abcdefghijklmnpoj" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
curl -s https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
printf "deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt focal main" |

Comment: focal main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infra.list
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install newrelic-infra -y
sudo systemctl start newrelic-infra

Comment: In my case I just need to run the below commands. Could you please help me to setup cloudinit.conf file with below content.

echo "license_key: abcdefgh12345667" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
curl -s https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
printf "deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt focal main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infra.list
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install newrelic-infra -y
sudo systemctl start newrelic-infra

Comment: Could you please help me in the same way how to run custom data via AKS node pool then I will reach my goal.Much appreciated your help.

Comment: Any update please? Much appreciated if you can provide update.

Comment: Just read the docs for cloudinit. Has plenty of examples: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html

Comment: I assume your commands just need to go under a `runcmd:` section